How to select specific edge loop?
I have this rectangular hole. I want to select the edges that I have marked in green.
I tried using Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops but depending on which edge I click I get one of the edge loops I have marked in red. How do I specifically select the green one?


Doesn't Alt-clicking on one of the edges work? If not there may be something odd with your topology.

I think if you can't select by alt+clicking, then this is because the set of edges doesn't satisfy the definition of an edge loop.

You have 2 options:

Option 1: Just manually select the edges
Option 2: Use the Pick Shortest Path Tool. You can activate this tool in edit mode by clicking on the first edge and then Ctrl +  Left Click the last edge. In this case you would probably select the first long edge then Ctrl +  Left Click the other long edge which would also select one of the short edges. You would, however, have to manually select the other short edge.

